# Copy or Create ZEROS-Tensor

Tags: pytorch, copy, new-operator, tensor

What is be good use torch-tensor: copy or create new tensor? What about speed?
The target is to get a ***new zeros tensor*** with constant size every time method is called.

```
class CopyOrCreateZeros:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fx = torch.zeros((800, 600))
        pass

    def method(self, x):
        """ this method will be used many ofter e.g. in loop """
        # do something

        new_x1 = torch.copy(self.fx)
        new_x2 = torch.clone(self.fx)
        new_x3 = x.new_zeros()
        new_x4 = torch.zeros_like(x)
        new_x5 = torch.zeros()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like cloning the `fx` tensor is the slowest solution while all three others (namely `Tensor.new_zeros`, `torch.zeros_like`, and `torch.zeros`) have comparable times:

- [`torch.clone`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.clone.html?highlight=clone#torch.clone):

  ```
  %timeit fx.clone()
  1000 loops, best of 5: 277 µs per loop
  ```
- [`torch.Tensor.new_zeros`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.new_zeros.html):

  ```
  %timeit fx.new_zeros(fx.shape)
  1000 loops, best of 5: 257 µs per loop
  ```
- [`torch.zeros_like`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.zeros_like.html):

  ```
  %timeit torch.zeros_like(fx)
  1000 loops, best of 5: 258 µs per loop
  ```
- [`torch.zeros`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.zeros.html):

  ```
  %timeit torch.zeros(fx.shape)
  1000 loops, best of 5: 256 µs per loop
  ```